# Rails5 + Passenger + Nginx: logs always go to stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, passenger

I have a Rails 5.0 app running in Passenger with Nginx as the web server.

I can't seem to get the app to output its logs into a file in `log/` under the Rails root directory.

`RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` is NOT set in my environment.

I can confirm that the log file I specify in `config/logs/production.rb` gets *created*, but subsequent logger output is not sent to it. My `log_level` is `debug`. Instead, the app sends all log output to STDOUT which Passenger dutifully appends to its own log file.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out when someone discussing logging for Rails apps mentioned Heroku's `rails_12factor` gem. I had moved this app from a previous Heroku deployment and didn't realize that gem would capture log output even when not deployed within a Heroku dyno.

The log file is used when the gem is removed.